# Need Help to debug the program for pic 16f877a

Tags: pic, c

I am a starter in PIC and I have done a program in pic c compiler for the following problem

---

When PIC A0 receives an input of more than 4 v, it is converted into digital output and that is fed to a counter. When the count reaches 5 the memory is incremented by 1 and is multiplied with 3 and displayed as cost as well as the counter is reset.

These are displayed in a LCD 16*2 screen. whenever the cost goes above 20, a message is sent via sms using a gsm 900 module to a pre described number. and finally the cost is reset to 0.

I have attached a word file of the program. The problems i face is the LCD display is not working as well as the message is not sent over the gsm.

---

Now the problem is program works fine with proteus model but in real time it doesn't work. Even the LCD 16*2 display is not displaying the result as well as there is no message being sent over the gsm.

Can anyone help me with this program and tell me what are the errors i have done..

Thanks in advance.. Hoping to receive some help.

This the program which i did for PIC 16f877a:

```
#include"C:\Users\vijay\Desktop\project\Program for\main.h"
#bit lcdrs=0X09.2
#bit lcde=0X09.0
#bit lcdrw=0X09.1
#byte lcddata = 0x8
void lcdinit();
void lcdclear();
void lcdclock();
void lcddly();
void line1();
void line2();
void lcdputc(char c);
//unsigned char disp[16],discou,dl;
void lcddly()
{
    delay_ms(1);
}
void lcdxy(char r,char c)
{ 
    if(r==1)
    {
        lcdrs=0;
        lcddata=0x80+c;
        lcdclock();
        lcdrs=1;
    }
    else if(r==2)
    {
        lcdrs=0;
        lcddata=0xC0+c;
        lcdclock();
        lcdrs=1;
    }
}
void lcdinit()
{
    lcde=0;
    lcddata=0x38;
    lcdrs=0;
    lcdclock();
    lcddata=0x14;
    lcdclock();
    lcddata=0x0c;
    lcdclock();
    lcddata=0x06;
    lcdclock();
    lcddata=0x01;
    lcdclock();
    lcdrs=0;
    lcddata=0x80;
    lcdclock();
}
void lcdclock()
{
    lcde=1;
    lcddly();
    lcde=0;
    lcddly();
}
void lcdclear()
{
    lcdrs=0;
    lcddata=0x01;
    lcdclock();
    lcddata=0x0c;
    lcdrs=0;
    lcdclock();
}
void lcdputc(char c)
{
    switch(c)
    {
    case '\f':
    {
        lcdrs=0;
        lcddata=0x01;
        lcdclock();
        lcddata=0x0c;
        lcdrs=0;
        lcdclock();
        lcdrs=0;
        lcddata=0x80;
        lcdclock();
        lcdrs=1;
        }break;
    case '\n':
    {
        lcdrs=0;
        lcddata=0xc0;
        lcdclock();
        lcdrs=1;
        }break;
    default:
        lcddata=c;

    lcdclock();
    }
}

int value;
int8 c=0,cost=0,d,u=0,a;
void main()
{
start:
    setup_adc_ports(AN0);
    setup_adc(ADC_CLOCK_INTERNAL);
    setup_psp(PSP_DISABLED);
    setup_spi(SPI_SS_DISABLED);
    setup_timer_0(RTCC_INTERNAL|RTCC_DIV_1);
    setup_timer_1(T1_DISABLED);
    setup_timer_2(T2_DIV_BY_16,127,1);
    setup_comparator(NC_NC_NC_NC);
    setup_vref(FALSE);
    set_adc_channel(0);
    delay_us(20);
    set_tris_b(0xFF);
    set_tris_d(0X00);
    set_tris_e(0X00);
    set_tris_a(0xF0);
    set_tris_c(0x0F);
    lcdinit();
    lcdclear();
    lcdxy(1,0);
    lcdclear();
    // for(qw=0;qw<=2;qw++)
    while(1)
    { 
        delay_ms(1);
        value=read_adc();
        lcdinit();
        lcdclear();
        lcdxy(1,0);
        lcdclear();
        lcdxy(1,0);
        printf(lcdputc, "count:%d",d);
        if(value>=31)
        { 
            c++;
            d=c;
            lcdinit();
            lcdclear();
            lcdxy(1,0);
            lcdclear();
            lcdxy(1,0);
            //delay_ms(100);
            printf(lcdputc, "count:%d",d);
        }
        if(d>=5)
        {
            u++;
            a=u;
            c=0;
            cost=(u*3);
            lcdinit();
            lcdclear();
            lcdxy(1,0);
            lcdclear();
            lcdxy(1,0);
            //delay_ms(100);
            printf(lcdputc,"Units:%d",a);
            printf(lcdputc, " Cost:%d", cost);
            goto start;
        }
        if (cost>=20)
        {
            //serial_init(9600);
            printf("AT\n");
            delay_ms(20); // 2 sec delay
            printf("AT+CMGF=1\n");
            delay_ms(20); // 2 sec delay
            printf("AT+CMGS=\"09825858509\"\n");
            delay_ms(20); // 2 sec delay
            printf ("Cost=%d ", cost); // sends ADC value as SMS
            putchar(26); // Ctrl-Z indicates end of SMS and transmit 
            delay_ms(20); // 2 sec delay 
            cost=0;
        } 
        else
        { 
            goto start;
        }
```

Comment: If the it works in Proteus, then your hardware connection has got the problem. Posting the schematic of your hardware connections may help.

Comment: I tried to indent your code because it was absolutely not readable. But I was not able to: some parenthesis are missing.

Comment: As a side comment: using labels and goto are very bad practice in that context. It may make sens in some very tricky context but in a simple project like to one presented you should avoid the usage of goto constructs. For the reason that is reduces A LOT the readability of the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiplied with 3 and displayed as cost" -- what is "cost"?  I think this is a translation error.

Answer (score 1):

Finally the underlying question is: how to perform debugging when working on the real target?

Well, it depends on the equipment your have around and the requirements of your design.
Some design may work fine when ran step by step and one can use an on site debugger like the ICD2. I am not up to date with microchip things and I don't know if the ICD3 supports the 16f877a.

Using such a debugger, one can run the code step by step and see what happens, if the flow is correct and inspect the content of every variable at any time.

BUT !

Some design are not happy with step by step debugging:

For instance, a motor controller will not be happy if you stop the code right at the middle of the control loop. Well in fact the controller won't care, but the controlled thing might get destroyed....

This is a extreme example, but if the thing connected to your MCU is timing critical, it makes debugging using an on site debugger more tricky. Not impossible, but more tricky.

One way to do the job is to go back to the Good Old Days where debuggers did exist or were to expensive and use methods of that time:

Such as:

- LED debugging ! Just add some LED to your design and enable them according to some conditions. You are then able to monitor theses conditions in real time. When checking timing, the LED can be replaced or kept and connected in parallel to an oscilloscope. That way you can check execution timings of your code, record timings etc, with very little impact on your code. But keep in mind that some additional cycles are required to toggle the LEDs pins.
- UART debugging. Send data using a UART to a PC to monitor internal things. **BUT** remember that the usage of the UART may drastically change the timing of your code. It depends on the way you implemented your UART handler: If it is interrupt based; using FIFOs or not; If it's a simple blocking function or not. 
  Sometime (in fact *often*) your code will work with the UART debugging in place and when the debugging stuff are removed it doesn't work anymore. This is likely a timing issue.